# Trying to create dynamic tables in React, getting bizarre error

Tags: reactjs, html-table

So, I'm trying to create a simple program in react.  The state is an array of objects.  It prints these objects into a table.  Standard table construction (, , ) etc. works fine for the initial render, but when I try to re-render I get bizarre errors I'm trying to adapt to.  So, this is my code so far.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

function Trains() {
  const [trainsList, setTrainsList] = useState([
    { name: "Thomas", destination: "Boston" },
    { name: "Duncan", destination: "New York" },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>name</thead>
        <thead>destination</thead>

        {trainsList.map((train) => (
          <tbody key={train.name}>
            <td>{train.name}</td>
            <td>{train.destination}</td>
          </tbody>
        ))}
      </table>
      <br />
      Train Name: <input type="text" id="trainName" />
      <br />
      Destination: <input type="text" id="trainDest" />
      <br />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setTrainsList((prev) =>
            prev.push({ name: "Dennis", destination: "Denville" })
          )
        }
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Trains />);
```

But even changing the table lingo like that still isn't enough.  I get these bizarre errors:

```
bundle.js:7294 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <thead>.
    at thead
    at table
    at div
    at Trains (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32:86)
```

And

```
bundle.js:7294 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>.
    at td
    at tbody
    at table
    at div
    at Trains (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32:86)
```

How on Earth can I create a table or use "thead" to any effect if I can't even put any text in the headings or put tds in my table rows?  How the heck do I make tables in react?

Comment: Both `<thead>` and `<tbody>` [require rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead#technical_summary) `<tr>`. You can't append cells or text directly to thead or tbody. These aren't "bizarre errors".

Answer (score 1):

### Table Rows

You've probably intended to make your table look something like that:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>destination</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {trainsList.map((train) => (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{train.name}</td>
        <td>{train.destination}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the `<tr>` elements to create a table rows both in the header and in the body.

### Key in a `map`

Also, note the `key` attribute in the `<tr>` element.  It is not a good practice to use an index of an array as a key, although it is much better that using a name that can be repeated.

### Fix setState

Finally, the function to update state after clicking a button can be rewritten to that:

```
<button
  onClick={() =>
    setTrainsList((prev) => {
      return [
        ...prev,
        { name: "Dennis", destination: "Denville" },
      ];
    })
  }
>
  Submit
</button>
```

Comment: This, but I think the <tbody> tag may need to be outside of the map function (and the `key` prop on the tr tag)

Comment: [@Julianna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20145313/julianna), sure — you're right!  I've made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `setTrainsList` method defined in the `Submit` button. The `push` method returns the new length of the array, but does not change the original array. Instead, you must use the `concat` method or the spread syntax to add a new element to an array in React:

```
<button onClick={() =>
    setTrainsList((prev) => [...prev, { name: "Dennis", destination: "your butt" }])
  }
>
  Submit
</button>
```

This should resolve the error and add a new element to the train list when you click the button.